# Encoding problems with German man pages

Tags: man, locale, character-encoding

On the machine I am working on I have English man pages under `/usr/share/man/`and German ones under `/usr/share/man/de`. The former are encoded with `us-ascii`, the latter ones with `utf-8`.

Unfortunately some special characters (Umlaute) in the German man pages are not displayed properly when calling `$ man some_command_with_german_manpage` with my current settings.

What are the correct settings in `/etc/man.conf` to resolve this issue? At the moment I have the following (omitting lines that I do think are not relevant):

```
TROFF           /usr/bin/groff -Tps -mandoc
NROFF           /usr/bin/nroff -Tps -mandoc -c
JNROFF          /usr/bin/groff -Tnippon -mandoc
EQN             /usr/bin/geqn -Tps
NEQN            /usr/bin/geqn -Tlatin1
JNEQN           /usr/bin/geqn -Tnippon
TBL             /usr/bin/gtbl
# COL           /usr/bin/col
REFER           /usr/bin/refer
PIC             /usr/bin/pic
VGRIND
GRAP
PAGER           /usr/bin/less -isR
BROWSER         /usr/bin/lynx
HTMLPAGER       /usr/bin/lynx -dump
CAT             /bin/cat
```

`$ locale` returns the following:

```
LANG=de_DE.utf8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.utf8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.utf8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.utf8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: text console, or X?

Comment: It's on an X terminal

Comment: But the same error occurs on a text console a swell.

Answer (score 0):

Normally `/etc/locale.gen` should have all the languages (and encodings) you need. Uncomment the langauge and run `locale-gen`. 
`man -Lde man` should then encode german properly. `de` for Deutch, `en` for English.